# Pdf isn't showing on one server, but when I put it on a different server everything is ok

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pdf

this is how the PDF looks like on my server that I have uploaded

[image]

this is the code that I have written for the PDF object

```
<div name='materiale' style="margin-left:150px">

<object width='720' height='620' data='data2/leja1.PDF'></object>
<p></p>
<object width='720' height='620' data='data2/leja2.PDF'></object>

</div>
```

but when I upload it on wamp or my friend's online server it works like a charm any idea what causes this? maybe server problems?
What would you guys recommend? is there any other way I can insert PDF files without changing the server ?

Comment: live server? can we see the url?

Comment: it will not be for much online but there it is:
http://merville.al/Lejandertimit.html

Comment: Have you had a look at the headers your wamp delivers the files in comparison to your server? Just a wild guess but maybe the problem is related to the "Content-Disposition" header send by your server.

Comment: When I look at your site in Safari (Mac), I get a notification that the Adobe Reader plug-in is blocked for your site (which is normal if it's the first time I visit a site). When I allow it, it displays the PDF properly.